# fetch_assoc() works only once in a loop

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm looping through 2 tables in MySQL DB (using fetch_assoc()). I would like to get the current id of the 1st table and all the ids of the second table on each iteration but I get the ids of the second table only on the first iteration. From the second iteration upwards, only the current id of the 1st table is returned. I would like to know what I'm doing wrong.

I've already tried for Loops and looked up similar questions here but none have really been of help.

```
<?php
$my_sqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'taskpro') or die(mysqli_error($my_sqli));
$data1 = $my_sqli->query("SELECT * FROM task_table") or die($my_sqli->error);
$data2 = $my_sqli->query("SELECT * FROM taskinfo") or die($my_sqli->error);

while ($row = $data1->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['id'];
    echo "<br>";

    while ($row2 = $data2->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row2['id'];
    } // end child loop

} // end parent loop

?>
```

This is the result I get

> 1
>
> 1234
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5
>
> 6
>
> 7
>
> 8
>
> 9
>
> 10

Comment: Because you have consumed ALL the resultset from the second query the first time round the outer loop. Basically got to EndOfFile so there is nothing more to fetch

Comment: Yes this is how it works, you need to `requery`. if you want to fetch the data again. Or kindly store both datas in array first and then do your operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is to read all the values from query2 into an array and then output the contents of the array in the loop:

```
$my_sqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'taskpro') or die(mysqli_error($my_sqli));
$data1 = $my_sqli->query("SELECT * FROM task_table") or die($my_sqli->error);
$data2 = $my_sqli->query("SELECT * FROM taskinfo") or die($my_sqli->error);

$rows2 = $data2->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
while ($row = $data1->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['id'];
    echo "<br>";

    foreach ($rows2 as $row2) {
        echo $row2['id'];
    } // end child loop

} // end parent loop
```

If for some reason you do need to iterate over the result set in the outer loop, you can use [`mysqli_data_seek`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php) to reset the pointer:

```
while ($row = $data1->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['id'];
    echo "<br>";

    while ($row2 = $data2->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row2['id'];
    } // end child loop
    // reset $data2 result pointer
    $data2->data_seek(0);

} // end parent loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I actually tried reading the results into an array (not using fetch_all() ) but with little luck. Thanks for shedding more light on this :)

Comment: @Nick Yes, I have. It works like a charm. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have exhausted the resultset of the second query after completing the first iteration of the outer query.

There are a few ways to do this, here are a couple of suggestions

First you could load all of the results from the second query into an array and then just re-process the array each time round the outer loop.
However, the `fetch_all()` funtion is only available if you have the MYSQL Native Driver installed. (MYSQLIND)

```
<?php
$my_sqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'taskpro');
if (!$my_sqli) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_errno());
}

$data1 = $my_sqli->query("SELECT * FROM task_table") or die($my_sqli->error);
$data2 = $my_sqli->query("SELECT * FROM taskinfo") or die($my_sqli->error);

$allData2 = data2->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

while ($row = $data1->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['id'];
    echo "<br>";

    foreach ( $allData2 as $row ) {
        echo $row2['id'];
    }
} // end parent loop
?>
```

Or you could use the `mysqli_result::data_seek()` function to reset the pointer to the first row of the query result like this

```
<?php
$my_sqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'taskpro');
if (!$my_sqli) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_errno());
}

$data1 = $my_sqli->query("SELECT * FROM task_table") or die($my_sqli->error);
$data2 = $my_sqli->query("SELECT * FROM taskinfo") or die($my_sqli->error);

while ($row = $data1->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['id'];
    echo "<br>";

    $data2->data_seek(0);   // make sure the pointer is at the beginning before looping
    while ($row2 = $data2->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row2['id'];
    } 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need the `while` loop at all. It is just confusing you. You could simply use `foreach($data1 as $row)`. Having said that, it would not solve your problem.

To solve your problem call [`fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) on the result from `query`, or simply chain them together. Be careful, this works only with static queries. If you need to use variables in your SQL, you should use [prepared statements](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli#prepare).

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'taskpro');
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');

$data1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM task_table")->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$data2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM taskinfo")->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach ($data1 as $row) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['id'];
    echo "<br>";
    foreach ($data2 as $row2) {
        echo $row2['id'];
    } // end child loop
} // end parent loop
```

I have also removed the manual error checking from your code, which was only obstructing your code and should really not have place in your working code. Read [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439).